# Take more than one value to make a table with Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

With my code I can join two Excel databases in 1. The problem is that it only shows me the Revenue column and not the column impressions. To be more clear I leave the code and the examples. I tried with:

```
 df1 = df1.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values=['Impresiones','Revenue'])
```

But I have an error with that: `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel

# Leemos ambos archivos y los cargamos en DataFrames
df1 = pd.read_excel("archivo1.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("archivo2.xlsx")

# Pivotamos ambas tablas
df1 = df1.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values='Revenue')
df2 = df2.pivot(index = "Cliente", columns='Fecha', values='Revenue')

# Unimos ambos dataframes tomando la columna "Cliente" como clave
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index =True, left_index = True, how='outer')
merged.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

# Creamos el xlsx de salida
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

with pd.ExcelWriter("Data.xlsx",
                    engine='xlsxwriter',
                    date_format='dd/mm/yyyy',
                    datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:

    merged.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

archivo1:

[image]

archivo2:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Necessary:

[image]

Here are the dataframe as text:

```
archivo1:
Fecha   Cliente Impresiones Revenue
21/12/17    Jose    12345   $989
21/12/17    Martin  3245    $10
21/12/17    Pedro   645     $879
21/12/17    Esteban 2345    $899
21/12/17    Mauro   654     $98

archivo2:
Fecha   Cliente Impresiones Revenue
20/12/17    Esteban 12345   $150
20/12/17    Martin  3245    $20
20/12/17    Pedro   645     $3000
20/12/17    Mauro   2345    $50
20/12/17    Jose    654n    $667
```

Comment: Can you paste your dataframes as text into your pictures?

Comment: I just edited it @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- join together both df
- reshape for column with categories `Impresiones` and `Revenue`
- sorting index, second level descendent
- change first level of index by mask and set to index

---

```
df = (pd.concat([df1,df2])
        .set_index(["Cliente",'Fecha'])
        .stack()
        .unstack(1)
        .sort_index(ascending=(True, False)))

m = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Impresiones'
df.index = np.where(m, 'Impresiones', df.index.get_level_values(0))
print (df)
Fecha       20/12/17 21/12/17
Esteban         $150     $899
Impresiones    12345     2345
Jose            $667     $989
Impresiones     654n    12345
Martin           $20      $10
Impresiones     3245     3245
Mauro            $50      $98
Impresiones     2345      654
Pedro          $3000     $879
Impresiones      645      645
```

Comment: Great, and if I have another colum like `Impresiones` call `Impresiones two` and I'm looking for add it too in the xlsx file. Whatdo  I need to change of the code??

Comment: I think you need add `m1 = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'Impresiones two'
df.index = np.where(m1, 'Impresiones two', df.index.get_level_values(0))`, but I am on phone only, so untested.

Comment: I tried with that but I have this error: ` IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2`